# How do you get the template type from a List Type?

Tags: c#, templates, reflection, types

I've been looking around for this for awhile. I would like to know how to get the type of the template passed into creating a list. For example.

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
```

How would I get the string type from this? I know how to use the type to get the fields and find the list type but not the template within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this instance, you can get it like this

```
Type genericType = listOfStrings.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Note that if you try this on a non generic type, it will fail because the length of the GetGenericArguments array will be 0, but you can of course take measures to control the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about getting type of items that are stored in this list?

```
listOfStrings[0].GetType()
```

will return you the type.

Edit:

This is the correct solution:

```
Type type = listOfStrings.GetType();
Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

Comment: This will **not** work if the list is empty, or if a type that inherit from T is added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

But perhaps he wants to know how to get the T when calling a function...

```
void MyFunc<T>(List<T> list) {
    /// T is the type passed to the List<T>, so for a List<int>, T is int
    T element = default(T);
    list.Add(element);
}
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want to use reflection. He simply wants to create new elements for his list in a "generic" way. I'm going "the opposite" direction from everyone else. My response was already "complete", but now it's "more complete" because I have added an example of use.

Comment: I see your point, but I don't think this is what he is asking. See the part of the question where he say `How would I get the string type from this?`. You do not get the type string from anywhere. I see no way around reflection here.

Comment: If the questioners knew how to express what they want, the world would be much easier :-) Many of them are as lost as the persons who ask the programmers for a feature (the users). In the end there are already various answers that use reflection and get one thing. I give ANOTHER thing. No one can pry in the head of the OP and know what he wants.